# Using JAX-RS how to collect an array of data returned by an API service into a list of java objects?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, helidon

What is the correct way to get List of objects from an API service using JAX-RS?

Environment: Helidon (MP 1.4.4), Java 8. The external api service returns an Array of objects. `Paper` is a POJO.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
...
...
public List<Paper> getPapers() {
   return client
            .target(REST_URI)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("api-key", "xxxxxx")
            .get(new GenericType<List<Paper>>() { });
}
```

Error:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Can't deserialize JSON array into: class java.lang.String
```

Comment: I suggest using Jackson as your JSON provider instead of JSONB

Comment: What does Paper look like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use arrays instead of `List`. Of course you can still convert the array to a `List` or any other collection type if you need.

```
public Paper[] getPapers() {
   return client
            .target(REST_URI)
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header("api-key", "xxxxxx")
            .get(Paper[].class);
}
```